# ApostropheCMS - Error: render() must not be called from a Nunjucks helper function nested inside another call to render()

Tags: apostrophe-cms, nunjucks

I have Apostrophe CMS project running in the production. Recently I've updated the app and also updated Apostrophe CMS version. After this I repeatedly get this error:

```
Error: render() must not be called from a Nunjucks helper function nested inside another call to render(). Use partial() instead.
```

The thing is that I can't inspect where this error is coming from. Also this happened very randomly. In the dev server I don't have this issue and can not replicate in order to find the root cause. After the above error it shows also Nunjucks error lines where the error supposed to happened, but that error lines are useless, because if I check the template there is nothing written in the specified error line.

I've checked the Apostrophe CMS source code. It throws the error here:

```
...
// Implements `render` and `renderString`. See their
// documentation.

    self.renderBody = function(req, type, s, data, module) {
      if (self.contextReq && (req !== self.contextReq)) {
        throw new Error('render() must not be called from a Nunjucks helper function nested inside another call to render(). Use partial() instead.');
      }
...
```

In my app code, I haven't used the `render()` function anywhere. 
NOTE that I randomly get this error in any kind of pages. There are several pieces pages I've created, where get the error too. Even in `notFound.html` template (where I have no any widgets, it just extends the `layout.html`) I get the error there too.

**Updates**

Based on the Nunjucks error lines I found that the error happens on my `my-pieces-pages/views/show.html` template at the below line:

```
{{ apos.singleton(piece, 'picture', 'apostrophe-images') }}
...
```

where `picture` field in the piece has the following look:

```
{
      name: "picture",
      label: "Picture",
      type: "singleton",
      widgetType: "apostrophe-images",
      options: {
        limit: 1
      }
    },
...
```

Comment: hi karlen, not having seen this in our code, I would need you to create an open source project with steps to reproduce the crash.

Comment: hi tom! The thing is that I can't reproduce the issue, it happens very randomly and I have no idea how to reproduce the same issue. The server works, however accidentially it might produce the error and after few seconds when you refresh the page again, the issue goes and it works normally.

Comment: @TomBoutell - Could you know when `req !== self.contextReq` case most probably can happen? If I don't directly call `render()` or `partial()` function.

Comment: Please take your project and start removing functionality, in a branch of course, until it no longer fails. You need to narrow down the cause, then share a smaller site that still exhibits the problem. You could also work with us via enterprise support.

Comment: It appears likely your code is attempting to invoke asynchronous operations (callbacks, promises, async functions) during template rendering. This is not possible and will lead to the kinds of errors you are seeing. You must use a promise event handler or widget `load` method for this purpose.

Comment: @TomBoutell thanks, but I did nothing like that. I have the same issue in `notFound.html` template, where besides changing few html codes I did nothing. Then what about in this case? I have that async related doubts in the source code of the framework rather than in my code. Because it started to produce this error after upgrading the Apostrophe. This is very disappointing.

Comment: I just fired up the `apostrophe-open-museum` project and hit it with 1000 requests for the home page via the "ab" load balancing tool. The issue did not occur.

Does this always involve a logged-in user perhaps?

Comment: Sorry for the frustrated tone of my earlier comment. This is an odd one because we persistently can't reproduce it. A lot of refreshes in various logged-in tabs didn't reproduce it in node 12 either.

Comment: I have raised the bounty for steps to reliably reproduce this bug to a full hour of enterprise support time: https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/2012

Comment: I see  @TomBoutell. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was discussion of this in a github issue as well. Eventually it was determined that all of those who experienced this issue were using early releases of Node 12.x.

The issue is not reproducible with the latest version of Node 12.x according to everyone who has made the attempt.

So, upgrading to the latest minor and patchlevel release of Node 12.x is the answer to this question. However if a means to reproduce it with the latest Node 12.x release is found steps to reliably reproduce it should be submitted via github and the ticket can be reopened.

For the sake of completeness it should also be noted that template code should never attempt to execute async functions or functions that take callbacks. I understand that this was not happening in your case.